# Module not found error: Can´t resolve path

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was working on my nodejs reactjs app an suddenly it stopped working. I just added a block of code to do a delete request and my app crashed but i am pretty sure it does nothing to do the error with my code.

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 24:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN\MERN-course\client\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
```

The above is one of the many errors that are being displayed in my console.

I know for sure my code has nothing to do with it because it is just an axios.delete request and if i comment the block of code the errors don´t go away.

Any solution to this?

This are my react versions:

```
"packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.2.0",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      }
```

My node versions

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "Mateo Ghidini",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "gravatar": "^1.8.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.4",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  }
```

Comment: Seems like the block of code you added used `body-parser`.   This was an old external module that was used frequently in ExpressJS apps.   The module doesn't exist in your dependencies, so either install it or rework your code using the Express v4.16.0+ examples so that you're not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack 5 has a bunch of breaking changes, as with any major release.

So you must do as the error messages says and both configure webpack to use a polyfill for each node core module (it suggests the polyfill webpack 4 uses), and install the polyfill. Of course, you can't change the react-scripts webpack config, so you're stuck.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12072#issuecomment-1074566504